# Number of users browsing the cart

Tags: magento-1.9

Admin>Customers>Online Customers does not tell you much about users browsing the site.

Has anyone found a solution to see how many people from unique IPs are shopping the site? And what page they are on? What city / country they are from? Are the users real users or robots?

Comment: Google analytics?

Comment: Analytics does not display robot visits! And looking for a solutions within Magento.

Comment: @user2774042 -- it's common practice to disallow robots from visiting cart and checkout pages (there's no need for a search engine to index these, anyways) using robots.txt, with directives such as ``Disallow: / checkout /``

Comment: [Magento Connect with query "realtime analytics](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=realtime+analytics&t=0&p=1)